# errors i cant understand in cpp

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class node{
 int data;
 node *next;
public:
  void setdata(int data_received){
    this->data=data_received;
  }
  void setnext(node* next_received){
    this->next=next_received;
  }
  int getdata(){
    return data;
  }
  node* getnext(){
    return next;
  }
};
class graph{
  node vertices[5];
  int number_of_vertices=0;
public:
  graph(int nov){
    cout<<"constructor running"<<endl;
    int vertex;
    this->number_of_vertices=nov;
  for (int i = 0; i < nov; i++) {
    cin>>vertex;
    vertices[i].setdata(vertex);
    vertices[i].setnext(NULL);
  }
}
  void display_vertex_array(){
    cout<<"displaying the array"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_vertices; i++) {
      cout<<vertices[i].getdata()<<" ";
    }
  }
  void add_vertex(int vertex3){
    cout<<"adding vertex  "<<vertex3<<endl;
    vertices[number_of_vertices].setdata(vertex3);
    number_of_vertices++;
  }
  void add_edge(int vertex1,int vertex2){
    /* everything else works fine except this part
    cout<<"adding an edge between  "<<vertex1<<"  and  "<<vertex2<<endl;
    node *vertex1_itr;
    node *vertex2_itr;
    vertex1_itr=find(vertices,vertices+number_of_vertices,vertex1);
    vertex2_itr=find(vertices,vertices+number_of_vertices,vertex2);
    if(vertex1_itr==(vertices+number_of_vertices)) {
      this->add_vertex(vertex1);
    }
    if(vertex2_itr==(vertices+number_of_vertices)){
      this->add_vertex(vertex2);
    }
    */
    node newnode1;
    node* newnode1_ptr=&newnode1;
    newnode1.setdata(vertex2);
    newnode1.setnext(vertices[vertex1].getnext());
    vertices[vertex1].setnext(newnode1_ptr);
    node newnode2;
    node* newnode2_ptr=&newnode2;
    newnode2.setdata(vertex1);
    newnode2.setnext(vertices[vertex2].getnext());
    vertices[vertex2].setnext(newnode2_ptr);
    }
};
int main(){
  cout<<"your list of 3 vertex"<<endl;
  graph adjacency_list(3);
  adjacency_list.display_vertex_array();
  cout<<endl;
  adjacency_list.add_edge(0,1);
  adjacency_list.add_edge(0,2);
  adjacency_list.display_vertex_array();
  cout<<endl;
  adjacency_list.add_edge(1,3);
  adjacency_list.add_edge(2,3);
  adjacency_list.add_edge(3,4);
  adjacency_list.display_vertex_array();
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

error is:

```
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:
In instantiation of 'bool
gnu_cxx::ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with
_Iterator = node; _Value = const int]':  C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:
required from '_RandomAccessIterator
std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator,
_Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = node; _Predicate = gnu_cxx::ops::_Iter_equals_val]' 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:
required from '_Iterator std::find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator,
_Predicate) [with _Iterator = node*; _Predicate = gnu_cxx::ops::_Iter_equals_val]' 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3790:28:
required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with
_IIter = node; _Tp = int]'  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:52:66: required from here 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17:
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'node' and 'const
int')  { return it == _M_value; }  ^  In file included from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:5:
note: candidate: template bool gnu_cxx::operator==(const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)  operator==(const
normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& lhs,  ^ 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:5:
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:  In file
included from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17:
note: 'node' is not derived from 'const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'  { return *it ==
_M_value; }  ^  In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:827:5:
note: candidate: template bool gnu_cxx::operator==(const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)  operator==(const
normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& lhs,  ^ 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:827:5:
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:  In file
included from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17:
note: 'node' is not derived from 'const
gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'  { return *it ==
_M_value; }  ^  In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:41,

from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5:
note: candidate: template bool gnu_cxx::operator==(const
gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&) 
operator==(const new_allocator<_Tp>&, const new_allocator<_Tp>&)  ^ 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5:
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:  In file
included from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40, 
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
from
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
from C:\Users\hp\Desktop\adjacency_list.cpp:1: 
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17:
note: 'node' is not derived from 'const gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>' 
{ return *__it == _M_value; }  ^
```

Comment: this is an adjacency list representation for undirected graph

Comment: `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'node' and 'const int')`: `find(vertices,vertices+number_of_vertices,vertex1);` You asked it to find an integer in an array of nodes. There is no equality operator between nodes and integers.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting on your error messages, but the formatting issues are in your original text (bad line breaks, missing indentation).

Comment: thanks , i understand the issue here but how do i fix it . say i have to find if there exists a node with its data field = 2

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `this->` unless the method parameter has the same name as the data member.  You can eliminate this case by choosing different naming conventions for the data members, such as prefixing with `m_` or adding an "_" suffix.

Comment: Which book are you using that says to use the `this->`?

Comment: no book, i learned bits and pieces of a lot of languages from youtube. fairly new to programming so some mistakes are bound to happen. but i will take suggestions on a book if you have any as most of the youtube lectures are short and not that deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node vertices[5];
int vertex1;

vertex1_itr=find(vertices,vertices+number_of_vertices,vertex1);
```

The problem is that `find` expects to be able to compare for equality it's third argument with elements in the range specified by the first two arguments. In other words the code above is comparing a `node` with an `int`. But in your code there is no `operator==` that takes a `node` and an `int`. That's what the error is telling you.

Simple answer is to use `find_if` and supply a predicate function. Lambda functions are useful for this

```
vertex1_itr = find_if(vertices,
    vertices + number_of_vertices,
    [=](const node& node){ return node.getdata() == vertex1; });
```

That code finds the first vertex whose data member is equal to `vertex1` which I think is what you were trying to do.